# Face recognition using SVM

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have tried implementing the SVM for face-recognition and below is the code I used for training and testing. The problem is that I am not getting accurate results and I am always getting the predict value as "0" sometimes.

Can some one help me out with the correct SVM parameters.

**Training code:**

```
static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& label, char separator = ';') {
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    if (!file) {
        string error_message = "No valid input file was given, please check the given filename.";
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    string line, path, classlabel;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream liness(line);
        getline(liness, path, separator);
        getline(liness, classlabel);
        if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
            Mat testimage = imread(path, 0);
            imshow("testimage", testimage);
            waitKey(10);
            images.push_back(testimage);
            label.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str()));
        }
    }
}
int svm()
{
    // Data for visual representation

     string fn_csv = string("/home/resize.csv");
//     These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels.
    vector<Mat> images;
    vector<int> label;
//     Read in the data. This can fail if no valid
//     input filename is given.
    try {
        read_csv(fn_csv, images,label);
    } catch (cv::Exception& e) {
        cerr << "Error opening file \"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: " << e.msg << endl;
//         nothing more we can do
        exit(1);
    }
    // Set up SVM's parameters
     Mat labelsMat(label.size(), 1, CV_32FC1);
      Mat trainingDataMat(images.size(),70*70, CV_32FC1);

                //iterating through the rows
      int c=0;int d;
               for (int j = 0; j <label.size(); j++) {
                    //iteration through the columns
                   d=0;
                   c++;
                    labelsMat.at<float>(j,0)=float(label[j]);
                  for (int r = 0;r<images[j].rows; r++) {
                //iterating through the rows
               for (int c = 0; c <images[j].cols; c++) {
                 trainingDataMat.at<float>(j,d++) = images[j].at<uchar>(r,c);

                }
                  }
               }

     //imshow("first",images[7]);
      cout<<"labels"<<labelsMat<<std::endl;
   cout<<"labels size"<<c<<std::endl;
   // CvSVMParams params;

SVMParams params = SVMParams();
params.svm_type = SVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = SVM::LINEAR;
params.degree = 3.43; // for poly
params.gamma = 0.00225; // for poly / rbf / sigmoid
params.coef0 = 19.6; // for poly / sigmoid
params.C = 0.5; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC , CV_SVM_EPS_SVR and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
params.nu = 0.0; // for CV_SVM_NU_SVC , CV_SVM_ONE_CLASS , and CV_SVM_NU_SVR
params.p = 0.0; // for CV_SVM_EPS_SVR
params.class_weights = NULL; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC
params.term_crit.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
params.term_crit.max_iter = 1000;
params.term_crit.epsilon = 1e-6;

    // Train the SVM
    CvSVM SVM;
    SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
  // cout<<"train row" <<trainingDataMat.rowRange()<<"cols"<<trainingDataMat.cols<<std::endl;
 SVM.save("/home/test.yml");

    return 0;
```

}

**Prediction Code:**

```
int svm_test()
{

    // Train the SVM
    CvSVM SVM;

  Mat test=imread("/home/n2.jpg",0);
//  cout<<"image size"<<(float(test.size))<<std::endl;
Mat test_mat(1,test.cols*test.rows,CV_32FC1);
  int ii1=0;
 for (int i1 = 0; i1<test.rows; i1++) {
                //iterating through the rows

                for (int j1 = 0; j1 < test.cols; j1++) {
                    //iteration through the columns

                 test_mat.at<float>(0,ii1++) = test.at<uchar>(i1,j1);
               // labels.at<float>(filenum,1);//=float(filenum);
                }
            }
  // waitKey(0);
SVM.load("/home/smile.yml");

cout<<"preditction value"<<SVM.predict(test_mat)<<std::endl;


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

well your code looks dirty so I won't be going over them but I will try to give your some hints on the process.

First you need training set and make sure you have more negative training data than positive for good results. Also note that your will need quiet a large number of faces for good result and perhaps around 100-200 for average or below average simple classifier.

Second extract features from the face, where you can use like, Color, Edge Histograms or Binary like Patters, etc. Choice is yours. But convolution of few will give more better results.

Train SVM using the prepared data and do predicition.

Here is a link from Roy a MIT student where he used SVM to train a food classifier. Code is simple to understand and you can follow them to get a gist of SVM classifier.

[Food Classifier](https://github.com/royshil/FoodcamClassifier)